# python -how to grep column from first row from log

Tags: python

I would like to grep 3rd column in a log my log shows in this way.

```
20150430|10:51          TATA_ISP_PING           193403          193195          193630
20150430|10:52          TATA_ISP_PING           193407          193291          193548
```

i need a condition if 3rd column prints 0 then i would get alert on this so i am trying to write python script on this

i have tried some logic but it is not working

```
import csv

#generated file should be in the format:
#SYMBOL,LOT_SIZE,OTHERSYMBOLNAME,PRICE_FACTOR
import time
folder = (time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
file_name = '/home/isp/pingLog'

instr_def = []

with open(file_name, 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|')
        i = 0
        for row in reader:
                print row[4]
                if i > 1:
                r = row[1](csvfile, delimiter=' ')
                        price_factor = 1
                        if "TAT_ISP_PING" in row[0]:
                                print "TATA_ISP_PING"
                                if 1:
                                        print "mail"
                        if "WDO" in row[0][0:3]:
                                instr_def.append( row[0]+ ',10,,1' )

                i = i+1

for item in instr_def:
        print item
```

Comment: In your example, the third column is `10:52 TATA_ISP_PING 193407 193291 193548`. So what does "if 3rd column prints 0" mean?

Comment: Also, your code doesn't seem to be checking for 0 anywhere, and I don't understand why you're looking at `row[4]`, `row[1]`, and `row[0]`—in fact, almost everything _but_ the third column. Plus, the code is full of indentation errors and syntax errors and things that are legal syntax but have no obvious intended meaning (what is `r = row[1](csvfile, delimiter=' ')` supposed to do?), so I can't guess what you were trying to do from the code, either.

Comment: actually if isp link goes down it will written 0 in 3rd column i am just testing that code not yet written completely can u guide me an easy way to test this code

Comment: Now I understand even less. You asked how to do something specific. Then you showed us some code that does something completely different. And now, you don't just want to know how to write tests for that different code?

Comment: Please show an example of a line with a 0 in third column. Also, you show a code using csv, but is really your file a csv or are the columns separated by a variable amount of white spaces? Currently, your question is unclear and could be closed.